# req.body retornando objeto vazio

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express.js, fetch

Bom dia pessoal, estou fazendo um post em uma api que criei, passo o body da seguinte forma

```
fetch(`${url}/teste`, {
   method: 'POST',
   body: JSON.stringify({"a": "teste"})
})
```

Na minha api tento pega o body da seguinte forma usando `axios`.

```
app.post('/teste', (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.body)
})
```

Porém ele retorna um objeto vazio `{}`, já tentei usando `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}))` e mesmo assim não funciona.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Tentou informar os _headers_ no `fetch`? Talvez passar um `mode: 'no-cors'`...

Comment: Fiz o teste agora e continua da mesma forma, vou tentar mais algumas coisas aqui

Comment: Consegui resolver... adicionando o seguinte header headers: {
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver adicionando o seguinte header no envio da request.

```
fetch(`${url}/teste`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({"a": "teste"})
})
```